# MongoDB Query select with inner select with Group By

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my old MYSQL database I use the following MYSQL query.
Because I migratie my database to mongoDB, I have to migrate the queries.

In my old mysql database I used the following query

```
SELECT idValue, 
       Timestamp, 
       Value 
FROM ( 
       SELECT * 
         FROM Metingen2 
        WHERE idGroep = 123 
     ORDER BY idValue ASC , 
              Timestamp DESC 
     ) 
 AS t GROUP BY t.idValue;
```

Can anybody explain how I can do a select in a inner select query?

I tried the following, but with no success:

```
$ops = array(
                array(
                    '$match' => array(
                                        'idGroep' => (int)123,
                                     )
                ),
                array(
                    '$sort' => array(
                        "idValue" => 1,
                        "Timestamp"   => -1,
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    '$group' => array(
                        "_id" => array("idValue" => '$idValue',                            
                                      ),
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    '$project' => array(
                        "_id" => '$_id.idValue',
                        "Timestamp" => '$_id.Timestamp',
                        "Value" => '$value',
                    ),
                ),

            );
            $cursor_metingen2 = $collection_metingen2->aggregate($ops);
```

Comment: Well your data is no longer in MySQL, it's in MongoDB. So show what the data looks like and the result you want to get from that data. The SQL has no relevance anymore, and amost always serves as a poor explanation of the problem. Just as it does not explain the problem here.

Comment: sorry I rewrite the question.

Comment: Don't see any re-writing here, but the SQL translation should be straightforward enough. You really should not ask "how to rewrite this SQL" but rather show the data and the expected result. It's a much clearer question with a wider audience. Put in SQL for reference only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a pass it looks like the query is trying to first order the content and then "GROUP" together using a "idValue" and returning the "first" results on the grouping boundary, after filtering out fo "idGroep" of course.

The inner select does not really do much here other than "filter" and "sort". The aggregation pipeline handles these differently, so what is happening in that execution is of little consequence. It's all about the results.

As such, your aggregation pipeline needs to do the same things:

```php
$cursor =  $collection_metingen2->aggregate(array(
    array(   
        '$match' => array( 'idGroep' => 123 )
    ),
    array(
       '$sort' => array( 
           'idValue' => 1,
           'TimeStamp' => -1
       )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
           '_id' => '$idValue',
           'TimeStamp' => array( '$first' => '$TimeStamp' ),
           'Value' => array( '$first' => '$value' )
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array( '_id' => 1 )
    )
));
```

Noting here that when you [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), not only must the other fields included use an "accumulator" such as [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) ( which should be correct here ) but you also "must" include everything you want in output.

It is a "pipeline", so the only thing that goes "into" a following stage is what comes "out" of the stage you specifiy.

And of course [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) "both" before grouping for the correct boundary values as well as at the "end" of the pipeline. The last sort is because `$group` does not guarantee keys in any order, but this may or may not be of any consequence to what is processing the results from here.

Also be careful with "casting", as unless you really need to convert to an integer type for comparison with data ( and you probably do not ) then you might get mismatched results. So only "cast" when you know you need to.